# Incorporar PPSX no HTML

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de incorporar um slide em formato .ppsx no html de um site. Quero evitar ter que executar o slide por alguns motivos.

Comment: Creio que somente convertendo, pois nativamente nenhum navegador suporta este formato, talvez o IE11 com ActiveX consiga usar junto a tag `<object>`, mas é algo restrito somente ao IE11 (se é que tem suporte activex para PPSX). Todavia você pode experimentar o serviço https://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppsx-to-html5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os navegadores não tem suporte para PPSX e dificilmente virão a ter, talvez com softwares de terceiros, mas isto dependerá de instalar algo na máquina.

Talvez o IE11 suporte se a instalação do Office oferecer ActiveX para isto, o que não é algo garantido.

Todavia lendo as respostas em:

- [Embed a PowerPoint presentation into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39855/1518921)

Você pode experimentar usar os serviço como GoogleDocs ou [**View Office documents online**](https://products.office.com/en-GB/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=b28c7173-79a2-4fb7-a1eb-9e75651fd1a1) e fazer o "embed" com `<iframe>`

Fazendo o upload para o googledocs e selecione o compartilhar ou então embarque assim:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://seusite/<arquivo>&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Ou gere o embed via [**View Office documents online**](https://products.office.com/en-GB/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=b28c7173-79a2-4fb7-a1eb-9e75651fd1a1), deve ficar semelhante a isto:

```
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://seusite/<arquivo>"></iframe>
```

---

### Extra

Existe uma ferramenta online chamada [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/ppsx-to-html), eles tem um serviço de API:

- https://cloudconvert.com/api

Lista de formatos suportados (incluindo o PPSX):

- https://cloudconvert.com/formats

No entanto é importante notar que isto é serviço com limites, se ultrapassar não será possivel usar, então se necessitar mais veja a https://cloudconvert.com/pricing

Com este serviço você pode realizar as tarefas de conversão online, segue a documentação https://cloudconvert.com/api/conversions

> **Nota:** troque `<API_KEY>` pela sua chave de acesso

O envio por HTTP deve ser assim para a URL `https://api.cloudconvert.com/process`, com o header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <API_KEY>
```

E o payload:

```
{
    "inputformat": "ppsx",
    "outputformat": "html"
}
```

No entanto existem facilitadores em PHP, como o https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-php (requer composer), exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \CloudConvert\Api;

$api = new Api("<API_KEY>");

$process = $api->createProcess([
    "inputformat" => "ppsx",
    "outputformat" => "html",
]);
```

Para Node.js existe o https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-node, exemplo:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    cloudconvert = new (require('cloudconvert'))('<API_KEY>');

cloudconvert.createProcess({
    "inputformat": "ppsx",
    "outputformat": "html"
}, function(process) {

});
```

E para python https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-python:

```
import cloudconvert

api = cloudconvert.Api('<API_KEY>')

process = api.createProcess({
    "inputformat": "flv",
    "outputformat": "mp4"
})
```

Comment: Não existe alguma API que ajude a converter e depois exibir ?

Comment: @wferreiracosta editei a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Ajudo muito, obrigado !!!